# CSS for sgwiggle (wavy) borders

Tags: css

I was able to achieve the borders below (see image) in CSS using the code below:

```css
.bottom,
.up,
.left,
.right {
  height: 30vh;
  position: relative;  
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

/* Text styling */
.bottom,
.up,
.left,
.right {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
/* */

.bottom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
}
.bottom::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px,
    #fff 12px,
    transparent 13px
  );
}

.up::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg); /*Very important*/
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
}

.up::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px,
    #fff 12px,
    transparent 13px
  );
}
```

Below is the corresponding HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bottom">4</div>
    <div class="up">5</div>
    <div class="left">6</div>
    <div class="right">7</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Sgwiggle bottom and top borders]

Now I want to achieve the same result for the left and right borders. I have this css so far:

```css
.left,
.right {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 49%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 9px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
}

.right::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /*Very important*/
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 48.5%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px,
    #fff 12px,
    transparent 13px
  );
}

.left::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg); /*Very important*/
  width: 100%;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -49%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 9px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    transparent 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
}

.left::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -48.5%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px 15px,
    #fff 12px,
    transparent 13px
  );
}
```

But this is the result that I get:
[image]

Could you please help figuring out what I am missing here?

Comment: Hi and welcome! HTML and CSS code must be inside in only 1 snippet otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: This would only work for a square. You need to make sure that your left and right pseudo elements are given the same height as the element and do the relevant rotations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://css-generators.com/custom-borders/) can help you

Example

```css
.box {
  --mask: 
    radial-gradient(30px at 25% 0,#0000 98%,#000) 50% 30px/120px 100% repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(30px at 75% 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) top/120px 60px repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}

div {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```